# getting a nameerror for maximum height function

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing

I am trying to make a program that will determine the maximum height of a ball thrown into the air using seperate functions that will each take input, determine if it is valid, and then calculate the height. I got the first two to work, but the maxHeight function will return a NameError saying it or one of the parameters is not defined. I know its something with the values from the input functions not being passed on. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
def isValid(h, v):
    if h and v > -1:
        pass
    else:
        print("Please enter a nonnegative number")
        getInput()


def getInput():
    h = int(input("Enter initial height of the ball:"))
    v = int(input("Enter initial velocity of the ball:"))

    isValid(h, v)
    return (h, v)


def maxHeight(h, v):
    height = h
    velocity = v
    maximum = height + (velocity / 32)
    return maximum


print(getInput())
print(maxHeight(h, v))
```

Example input and traceback

```py
Enter initial height of the ball:5
Enter initial velocity of the ball:5
(5, 5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test.py", line 23, in <module>
    print(maxHeight(h,v))
NameError: name 'h' is not defined
```

Comment: Please include also the used input values and the traceback of the error in the question. It will help people to find the question if needed, and people to write an answer.

Comment: Instead of modifying an answer, you can write comments below the answer

Comment: Regarding your question of `isValid` function working without `h` and `v` defined in the global scope: that is not possible. Perhaps you are using some sort of interactive shell (IPython, Jupyter notebook, Spyder, ..) and you had `h` and `v` in the global while you were testing your code.

Answer (score 1):

At the line `print(maxHeight(h, v))` you have not defined `h` or `v`. The `h` and `v` in the `getInput` exist only inside that function. You should take them out of the function to the global (module) scope:

```py
h, v= getInput()
print(h,v)
print(maxHeight(h,v))
```

Comment: okay I understand how that could be my problem but the isvalid function works with the values entered into the getInput function. why does that work and not the maxHeight function?

Comment: I commented to the question already, but the `isValid()` can not work either without input values from the global/module scope. You can try this yourself by printing both `isValid(h,v)` and `maxHeight(h,v)`. Either both of them work, or both of them do not work.